How to merge two videos with openshot?
I installed the latest version of OpenShot with
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openshot.developers/ppa
sudo apt update && sudo apt install openshot-qt python3-openshot

I want to merge two videos. I dragged them into the left pane in OpenShot. If I select both of them, and export, it is only exporting the video on which I clicked (although I selected both).
How to merge two videos using OpenShot in Ubuntu?
I am using Kubuntu 24.04.

I belive you can do it with losslesscut. Worth a try?

@graham I finally managed to do it with Shotcut. But feel free to write up your answer.

done. Glad you also found another solution.

Ensuring that both videos use the same codec, losslesscut is a useful tool for completing this task.

The task is made simple by first selecting the videos and sorting them in to the order required. When done, click on Open then `Merge'.
this useful YT video from TutorTube (acknowledgements) explains the process in a very short and uncomplicated way.

To do this in OpenShot, you should drag the clips to the timeline near the bottom of the window. Alternatively you can press the + toolbar button after you have selected the clip.
The timeline determines what will be exported, the selection in the list is just for the user interface.
